openssl message: Error querying OCSP responder
A couple of years ago I created a script to the response of a OCSP provider using the openssl ocsp
openssl ocsp -issuer /PATH/issuer.crt -serial 32464515085749554265854291628418826339  -url http://oscp.provider.com  -noverify
It worked fine until it started to report
Error querying OCSP responder
and I do not know why.
Is there any way to debug this command and find the root cause of the problem?
I read OCSP is actually a HTTP connection. Do you know any details to run a OCSP query using the either curl or wget tools?
Best regards

Yes, OCSP is usually HTTP, and this is confirmed by the URL for the responder.
For the current stackoverflow cert, issued by LetsEncrypt E1:
$ openssl x509 -in temp0 -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            03:e7:d5:79:37:f7:4f:e1:3e:7f:95:0e:c4:c3:75:a8:16:db
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
        Issuer: C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = E1
        Validity
            Not Before: May 11 20:14:33 2024 GMT
            Not After : Aug  9 20:14:32 2024 GMT
        Subject: CN = stackoverflow.com
        Subject Public Key Info: 
          [snip]
        X509v3 extensions:
            [snip]
            Authority Information Access:
                OCSP - URI:http://e1.o.lencr.org
                CA Issuers - URI:http://e1.i.lencr.org/
        [snip]
$ openssl x509 -in temp1 -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            b3:bd:df:f8:a7:84:5b:bc:e9:03:a0:41:35:b3:4a:45
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
        Issuer: C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X2
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep  4 00:00:00 2020 GMT
            Not After : Sep 15 16:00:00 2025 GMT
        Subject: C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = E1
        Subject Public Key Info:
            [snip]
        X509v3 extensions:
            [snip]

$ # GENERATE THE REQUEST 
$ openssl ocsp -issuer temp1 -cert temp0 -reqout req.der
$ xxd req.der
00000000: 3078 3076 304f 304d 304b 3009 0605 2b0e  0x0v0O0M0K0...+.
00000010: 0302 1a05 0004 14ef 9001 70dd 588f 2a65  ..........p.X.*e
00000020: 1e21 511f dcd0 bb6f 512b ab04 145a f3ed  .!Q....oQ+...Z..
00000030: 2bfc 36c2 3779 b952 30ea 546f cf55 cb2e  +.6.7y.R0.To.U..
00000040: ac02 1203 e7d5 7937 f74f e13e 7f95 0ec4  ......y7.O.>....
00000050: c375 a816 dba2 2330 2130 1f06 092b 0601  .u....#0!0...+..
00000060: 0505 0730 0102 0412 0410 e68e bfe7 8024  ...0...........$
00000070: ffc6 941e 5e36 849c 0d6d

$ # SEND USING POST
$ curl http://e1.o.lencr.org --data-binary @req.der -H "Content-type: application/ocsp-request" \
> -H "Accept: application/ocsp-response" -v -o resp.der --no-progress-meter
*   Trying 2600:1408:ec00:14::17d7:e4:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to e1.o.lencr.org (2600:1408:ec00:14::17d7:e4) port 80 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: e1.o.lencr.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Content-type: application/ocsp-request
> Accept: application/ocsp-response
> Content-Length: 122
>
} [122 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 122 out of 122 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Content-Type: application/ocsp-response
< Content-Length: 345
< ETag: "1F57E035189B8A286FDD9040EEA61B80F2D9E3CC14116C3005D217CB3011D6FD"
< Last-Modified: Thu, 16 May 2024 21:15:00 UTC
< Cache-Control: public, no-transform, must-revalidate, max-age=21486
< Expires: Fri, 17 May 2024 21:54:37 GMT
< Date: Fri, 17 May 2024 15:56:31 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
{ [345 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host e1.o.lencr.org left intact

$ # OR SEND USING GET
$ curl http://e1.o.lencr.org/$(base64 -w0 req.der) \
> -H "Accept: application/ocsp-response" -v -o resp.der --no-progress-meter
*   Trying 2600:1408:ec00:14::17d7:e4:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to e1.o.lencr.org (2600:1408:ec00:14::17d7:e4) port 80 (#0)
> GET /MHgwdjBPME0wSzAJBgUrDgMCGgUABBTvkAFw3ViPKmUeIVEf3NC7b1ErqwQUWvPtK/w2wjd5uVIw6lRvz1XLLqwCEgPn1Xk390/hPn+VDsTDdagW26IjMCEwHwYJKwYBBQUHMAECBBIEEOaOv+eAJP/GlB5eNoScDW0= HTTP/1.1
> Host: e1.o.lencr.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: application/ocsp-response
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Content-Type: application/ocsp-response
< Content-Length: 345
< ETag: "3AB85BAD920805EBF4D9D0BF467FB4E97E7500EEFC18BA074DEB336577209567"
< Last-Modified: Thu, 16 May 2024 21:18:00 UTC
< Cache-Control: public, no-transform, must-revalidate, max-age=21563
< Expires: Fri, 17 May 2024 21:58:22 GMT
< Date: Fri, 17 May 2024 15:58:59 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
{ [345 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host e1.o.lencr.org left intact

$ # IN EITHER CASE IF YOU GOT A GOOD RESPONSE (HTTP status 200 & body)
$ openssl ocsp -respin resp.der -noverify -text # or other options as desired
OCSP Response Data:
    OCSP Response Status: successful (0x0)
    Response Type: Basic OCSP Response
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    Responder Id: C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = E1
    Produced At: May 16 21:15:00 2024 GMT
    Responses:
    Certificate ID:
      Hash Algorithm: sha1
      Issuer Name Hash: EF900170DD588F2A651E21511FDCD0BB6F512BAB
      Issuer Key Hash: 5AF3ED2BFC36C23779B95230EA546FCF55CB2EAC
      Serial Number: 03E7D57937F74FE13E7F950EC4C375A816DB
    Cert Status: good
    This Update: May 16 21:15:00 2024 GMT
    Next Update: May 23 21:14:58 2024 GMT

    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
         30:65:02:30:5f:da:b1:a3:55:88:75:95:32:ed:c9:07:80:9d:
         53:c9:fd:81:b5:25:58:9a:fc:7b:b2:43:13:1a:c3:05:7d:de:
         c8:57:13:f3:71:ea:f5:00:d7:22:2f:9b:9c:ad:e8:b0:02:31:
         00:d5:fb:92:54:22:fb:4b:0d:46:8f:93:b1:a3:77:d5:cf:09:
         b0:fb:47:a8:23:3e:b1:c8:a9:34:17:74:d4:5a:84:b4:ff:69:
         96:76:52:e1:41:7e:cc:84:80:bf:c9:cd:cc

